# Template specialization on typename parameter being any instantiation of a particular template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, boost-mpl, template-templates

I have a class template `Z` that I would like specialize when passed a type that is an any instantiation of a particular template `N`:

```
struct L {
    template <typename S> void foo(S &) {/*...*/}
};

template <class T>
struct M {
    template <typename S> void foo(S &) {/*...*/}
};

template <class T>
struct N {
    template <typename S> void foo(S &) {/*...*/}
};

// I'd like to specialize this for TY==N<anything>
template <typename TX, typename TY>
struct Z {
    void bar(TX &tx) { /*...*/ ty->foo(tx); /*...*/ }
    TY *ty;
};
```

Since `Z<int, L>` and `Z<int, N<int>>` and `Z<int, M<int>>` are all valid use cases, I can't do anything along the lines of turning `Z` into a template template, and there is a compelling complexity reduction possible in `Z<TX, TY>::bar(TX &)` when `TY` is a class built from `N`.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should effect the specialization you desire:

```
template <typename TX, typename ANY>
struct Z< TX, N<ANY> > {
    // ...
};
```

`Z` gets specialized when the first parameter is `TX`, and the second parameter is `N<ANY>`. A quick illustration:

```
template <typename A> struct N { A a; };

template <typename TX, typename TY>
struct Z { Z () { std::cout << "not special" << std::endl; } };

template <typename TX, typename ANY>
struct Z< TX, N<ANY> > { Z () { std::cout << "special" << std::endl; } };

int main ()
{
    Z<int, int> z1;
    Z<int, N<int> > z2;
}
```

Results in the output:

```
not special
special
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I had fiddled with the signature but was unable to deduce the right one. I think I actually get the parameter syntax of templates in general a bit better now.

Comment: Glad to be of help. +1 on your question from me.